# Block boundaries of complex shape via css+html

Tags: html, css, overflow, markup, css-shapes

[image: Moving object]

On the image above the triangle is outer block, and the main block have `'overflow: hidden'`. During the animation part of the animated image is cropped. In the main block necessary boundaries of complex shape. Any ideas how is this possible? Requirement of browsers - top versions chrome or firefox.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/F7Cz9/

Comment: please post the relevant css+html and if possible provide a demo in a sandbox like jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: ok, example on jsfiddle added

Comment: thank you for the demo. What is the acutal result you want? Do you want parts of the image to be visible within the triangle or is the few white pixels on the bottom of the triangle that you want to see gone? In the demo i don't see the image beeing cropped. The triangle lays exactly over the border of the image container.

Comment: Current HTML not allow to achieve to the result what i want, it's only example of problem and temporary solution.  I want parts of the image to be visible within the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

This one is a little complex and I don't have all the styling down yet but by using pseudo-elements on a wrapper to create the triangle **above**...you can do it.

The hover is there just to show the "overflow" working.

[**Codepen.io Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/EGAdy)

**HTML**

```
<div class="super-wrap">
  <div class="imgwrapper">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-350-100-8.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.super-wrap {
  width:700px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
  border:1px solid grey;
}

.imgwrapper {
  width:700px;
  position: relative;

}

.imgwrapper img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0;
  transition:margin-left 1s ease;
}
.super-wrap:hover img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: It's work, but with more complicated styles(border-radius, border-top on main block ...) this method bring a lot of problem.

Now i'm trying use masking(mask css property) for get more convenient result.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is, in practical terms, the only way.